# Como obter o valor de um objeto Odata JSON e converter para string?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone, wcf

Após acesso ao WCF, obtenho a seguinte resposta:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "http://luiz-note64/WcfOper/WcfOperDataService.svc/$metadata#Operacoes&$select=IdOperacao",
    "value": [
        {
            "IdOperacao": "4234340"
        }
    ]
}
```

Como faço para extrair da resposta o Valor de `IdOperacao` para uma string?

Comment: Pode nos dizer claramente qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: Olá, Luiz, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, tente ser bem mais específico ao fazer uma pergunta, assim evita essa história de voto negativo, fechamento de pergunta, reabertura... e parte direto para solução do problema. Parece que com o que apresentou já é possível responder... talvez até já exista alguma pergunta/resposta pronta no site, o pessoal do C# é quem vai dizer. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 2):

Aqui está a Solução:

A resposta da chamada WCF:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "http://luiz-note64/WcfOper/WcfOperDataService.svc/$metadata#Operacoes&$select=IdOperacao",
    "value": [
        {
            "IdOperacao": "4234340"
        }
    ]
}
```

Abaixo o Código da chamada e a conversão do campo "IdOperacao" em
    string:

```
Uri xuri = new Uri(uri, "/WcfOper/WcfOperDataService.svc/Operacoes?&$format=json&$filter=OperGuid%20eq%2‌​0"+ "'" + objLocal.OperGuid + "'" + "&$select=IdOperacao"); 
string retorno = await oper.GetStringAsync(xuri); 
JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(retorno);  
var sidoperacao = jobject["value"][0]["IdOperacao"].ToString();
```

Ou seja: em `sidoperacao` está contido o Valor "4234340".